# Focusing radio button does not work by tab key in Angular material

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material

I am working with `angular material components` using `7.2.0` version.

when trying hit the radio button field with `tab` key, the field does not get focus and does not checked.

I created example for this in stackblitz.

[radio button stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c37tsw-7ncdpj?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html)

Any idea?

Comment: Use arrow keys after you get your first focus.

Comment: thanks, its work! didn't figure this out.